# Update WPF binding from Timer within ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, timer, binding

I have an `ObservableCollection<Tuple<RandomClass,TimerPlus>>` where `TimerPlus` is an extended version of `System.Timers.Timer`, and has a `DateTime` Property called "TimeLeft", which returns the time remaining for the timer to elapse.

I have an ItemsControl, which binds to the observable collection. I bind so some properties in Item 1 of the tuple, and I also want to bind to the DateTime TimeLeft in the TimerPlus (Item2). The binding works, however does not update with new values.

Inside TimerPlus I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and when the Start() is called on TimerPlus it starts a `DispatcherTimer` every second to raise `OnPropertyChanged("TimeLeft")`, but this doesn't work.

How do I have the ItemsControl pull the new remaining time left every second if this doesn't do it?

XAML (with some redaction of unimportant code)

```
<ItemsControl VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding WaitingMarkets}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF424242" BorderThickness="3" Margin="5">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Run Text="Market ID: "
                                         /><Run Text="{Binding Item1.MarketId}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Separator Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5">
                        <Run Text="Time Remaining: "
                        /><Run Text="{Binding Item2.TimeLeft, StringFormat='HH:mm:ss'}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

MarketID binds correctly from item1, and from item2 the TimeLeft binds correctly initially, but doesn't update.

The class for item 2 I have is as follows:

```
public class TimerPlus : System.Timers.Timer, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime m_dueTime;
    private DispatcherTimer ClockTimer;

    public TimerPlus() : base()
    {
        this.Elapsed += this.ElapsedAction;
    }

    protected new void Dispose()
    {
        this.Elapsed -= this.ElapsedAction;
        base.Dispose();
    }

    public DateTime TimeLeft
    {
        get
        {
            return new DateTime(2017,1,1) + (this.m_dueTime - DateTime.Now);
        }
        set { }
    }

    public new void Start()
    {
        this.m_dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(this.Interval);
        ClockTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
        ClockTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        ClockTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { OnPropertyChanged("TimeLeft"); }));
        };
        ClockTimer.Start();
        base.Start();
    }

    private void ElapsedAction(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.AutoReset)
        {
            this.m_dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(this.Interval);
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            if (handler.Target is CollectionView)
            {
                ((CollectionView)handler.Target).Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I have tried this without the Dispatcher.Invoke, and have tried passing "Item2.TimeLeft" as the parameter to OnPropertyChanged also.

Comment: Can you upload your code?

Comment: Please give us some part of your code

Comment: added xaml and the custom timer class code.

Comment: Calling Dispatcher.Invoke in the Tick handler of a DispatcherTimer makes no sense. The whole idea of a DispatcherTimer is that its Tick handler is automatically called in the thread where the DispatcherTimer was created, i.e. the UI thread. And what's that check of the handler.Target property in OnPropertyChanged good for? That really looks odd.

Comment: The check is because I copy the INotifyPropertyChanged Members from other classes, and when using a collectionview thats required to get it to refresh. If I'm not using a collectionview, it causes no harm just leaving it in.

Comment: Can you confirm that your handler is always populated when used in the list? It seems like your handler is possibly stopping the event from being raised. And handling `CollectionView` in what appears to be your `Model` class is not a good idea. Just use `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));`

Comment: Have you confirmed that your Tick event handler is actually being executed?